# Convert integer array into string

Tags: c, gcc

I have an integer array:

```
int s3[] = {97, 115, 100, 102, 103, 49, 50, 51, 37, 36, 33};
```

and I need its string value like `"asdfg123%$!"`

something like this:

```
printf ("%s", s4);   // and output should be => asdfg123%$!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy the array item by item in a loop and store each value in a `char`. Then null terminate that `char` array so that it becomes a string. Or alternatively don't declare `s3` as `int` to begin with.

Comment: If I am doing 


`char s4[] = {97, 115, 100, 102, 103, 49, 50, 51, 37, 36, 33};
printf ("%s", s4);
printf ("\n%d", sizeof(s4));`


getting the output like 

asdfg123%$!asdfg123%$!
11

Comment: @KshitijGupta You need to have a 0 at the end to terminate the string.

Comment: @KshitijGupta correct format specifier for printing `size_t` is `%zu`, not `%d`.

Comment: Use: `printf(”%.*s\n”, (int)sizeof(s3), s3);` with `s3` as a byte array.  This specifies how many bytes to format and doesn't read past the end of the array.

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  int s3[] = { 97, 115, 100, 102, 103, 49, 50, 51, 37, 36, 33 };
  // make sure s3 does not contain values above 127 (or 255 depending on
  // your platform).

  // temporary storage for the null terminated string
  char temp[100];   // must make sure s3 has no more than 99 elements

  // copy the values in s3 to temp as chars
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < sizeof(s3)/sizeof(int) ; i++)
  {
    temp[i] = s3[i];
  }

  // null terminate 
  temp[i] = 0;   

  // now we can print it with `printf` and `%s` because
  // now `temp` is a null terminated string.
  printf("%s\n", temp);
}
```

`sizeof(s3)` is the size of the `s3` array in bytes, `sizeof(int)` is the size of an `int`, therefore `sizeof(s3)/sizeof(int)` is the number of elements in the `s3` array.

---

**Advanced knowledge** (slightly above beginner level):

- Actually, you should even write `sizeof(s3)/sizeof(*s3)` which is cleaner because we don't need to repeat the `int` type.
- Instead of having a fixed size `char temp[100];` you could allocate the memory dynamically using `malloc` with the size `sizeof(s3)/sizeof(*s3) + 1` (+1 for the null terminator).
- ... or just use `char temp[sizeof(s3)/sizeof(*s3)+1];`

Comment: You could allocate `temp` with size `sizeof(s3)/sizeof(*s3)+1`.

Comment: @nielsen absolutely, but I wanted to keep things simple. Editing right now and suggesting this.

Comment: @nielsen you're right, deleting my comment regarding this, answer edited, you can delete your comment too.